# html audio player javascript loops inadvertently

Tags: javascript, html, avaudioplayer

I'm using a javascript link located in `<head>` section of my WP site. It's very simple and works well, except when the player ends the last track - it starts to play the first track again.

I tried to use `loop="false"` but it starts another bug, restarting the same last track. I'm not familiarized with coding javascript, but I think it should be possible to create a class, something like `class="last-song"` and play around with this.

An example can be seen in [here](https://fredericopeter.com.br/musicblog/files-vocal/smiths), where the HTML can be checked:

The javascript can be found [here](https://fredericopeter.com.br/musicblog/js/audioPlayer.js)

I would be very grateful if somebody could get some help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
$("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function(){
currentSong++;
if(currentSong == $("#playlist li a").length)
currentSong = 0;
$("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
$("#playlist li:eq("+currentSong+")").addClass("current-song");
$("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[currentSong].href;
$("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
});
}
```

when you set the `currentSong = 0;` after your `if(currentSong...` statement you're telling it to loop. Basically, you're resetting it back to the first song in the array every time it hits the end.

If you changed that to something like:

```
if (currentSong == $("#playlist li a").length) {
    $("#audioPlayer")[0].pause() // maybe .stop()
    // Do more stuff here for your UI
}
```

It also looks like you could just do nothing (just comment out the `currentSong = 0` line). For instance:

```
$("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function(){
    currentSong++;
    if(currentSong == $("#playlist li a").length)
    //currentSong = 0;
    $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
    $("#playlist li:eq("+currentSong+")").addClass("current-song");
    $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[currentSong].href;
    $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
});
```

Comment: You're welcome, could you mark it as the answer please?

Comment: All help are welcome, but I opted for the first solution at the top. Still, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[currentSong].href;
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
```

this is saying play the first in the array sequence

I am confused by the if statement as it doesnt appear to be doing anything

```
if(currentSong == $("#playlist li a").length)
```

as there are no curley brackets {} to specify what it is to do on the IF and ELSE

```
function audioPlayer(){
var currentSong = 0;
$("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[0];
$("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
$("#playlist li a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
    $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
    $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
    currentSong = $(this).parent().index();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current-song");
});

$("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function(){
    currentSong++;
    if(currentSong == $("#playlist li a").length){
        currentSong = 0;
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[currentSong].href;
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].pause();
    }else{
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[currentSong].href;
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
    }
    $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
    $("#playlist li:eq("+currentSong+")").addClass("current-song");
}
);
}
```

Comment: You don't need curly braces around single line if statements. I'm guessing it was just the formatting being messed up.

Comment: It works well, I think that solved. Many thanks for your answer!

Comment: Thats good tbat it worked for you, could you kindly click the vote up button so tbat i can be credited for helping you, thanks 

Comment: I'm new here and am not familiarized with this site. Where is located this button?

Comment: On the left there is a number 0 with up and down arrows next to my answer, if you felt my answer was helpful, click on the upward arrow, and it rewards me possitive reputation points for helping people